# Reload current frame in AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

What's the sanest way to achieve something along the lines of `this.gotoAndStop(this._currentframe)`?

What I want is that Flash re-loads the current frame as if I was using gotoAndStop (which does nothing if it is given the current frame as target frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand why you would want to do this, but what if you go to the frame before (or after) the current frame and then go back?

```
var current:int = _currentFrame;
gotoAndStop(current - 1);
gotoAndStop(current);
```

I haven't done AS2 in quite a while so I'm not at all sure what, if anything, the above code produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a movieclip class method on the frame in question

prevFrame()

Answer (score 0):

i use this command and this works for me

```
on (release) {
    prevFrame();
}

on (release) {
    nextFrame();
}
```